# incrementing the value of a input field in the cloned row

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

1)here i'm doing clone of a row...but this code is working only in eclipse [ ie ,cloning   is working ] and it is also not working in any browsers.

2)What is the solution to get the values of text boxes in the cloned rows having same name, and insert into the database using jsp and servlet?
how can i get those values with same name

3)i have servlet code to get only single value from jsp

```
    String address_seq_num =request.getParameter("address_seq_num");

how can i get the value of address seq number in the cloned row fromjsp to servlet to insert into the next row of a table in the database.
```

4)if i mention "DOCUMENT TYPE" to this code ,it will not work in eclipse also.....
please guide me...

JavaScript

```
function clonetable() {
 var x=document.getElementById("main_table"); //get the table 
var rowCount = x.rows.length; 
var row = document.getElementById("table_row_clone"); // find row to copy
var table = document.getElementById("table_body"); // find table to append to 
var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too 

var tb1 = clone.document.getElementById("asn");//here i'm incrementing the value     
tb1.value=rowCount+1;//of "address seq num " in the cloned row


    clone.id = "abc"; // change id or other attributes/contents 
    table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table 
}

function deltable() {
    var x = document.getElementById("main_table"); //get the table 
    var rowCount = x.rows.length;
    if (rowCount > 1) {
        x.deleteRow(rowCount - 1);
    } //delete the last row 
}
```

HTML

```
<table id="main_table" align="center" style="width:75%">
    <tbody id="table_body">
        <tr id="table_row_clone">
            <td>
                <table align="center" style="width:100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div style="border:3px solid silver;border-radius:5px;background-color:grey">
                                <table width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th align="center">Address Details</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div style="border:3px solid silver;border-radius:5px;background-color:#1E90FF">
                                <table align="center" style="width:99%">
                                    <tr style="background-color:#1E90FF">
                                        <td style="width:35%">
                                            <table width="100%">
                                                <tr id="slrow">
                                                    <td style="width:43%">Address Seq Num</td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <input id="asn" style="width:60px" name="address_seq_num" type="text" value="1" readonly>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="49%" align="right">
                                            <input style="width:80%" type="text" value="Reg.office/Primary Office">
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <input style="width:30px" type="button" value="+" onclick="clonetable()">
                                            <input style="width:30px" type="button" value="-" onclick="deltable()">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: where are you incrementing? I don't see it in your JS code

Comment: Your HTML mark up is messy and a lot of elements have not been closed. I suggest. you post a cleaner html mark up with proper closing and ending of element tags.

Comment: thank you for your reply...actually in this code i want to increment "Address seq number" in the next row after cloning...currently its value is "1"...but i dont know how to do that....i tried this code var tb = document.getElementById("asn");
tb.value = parseInt(tb.value, 10) + 1; it increments the value, but it also changing the first row value upon successive additon...

Answer (score 0):

Per your HTML (which is messy, by the way) you can increment that textbox's value with something like:

```
var tb = document.getElementById("asn");
tb.value = parseInt(tb.value, 10) + 1;
```

The trick is you have to cast the textbox's value into a number, which is what parseInt is doing in that example.

Note that the above snippet will give you "NaN" in the textbox if the value is not a valid number - it's not doing any data validation at all.

Comment: thank you for the reply....i tried this code...it increments the value, but it also changing the first row value upon successive additon...

Comment: Yeah so that means you have the same id propagating throughout your rows.  You'll need to uniquely identify the row somehow then.  In other words, the document.getElementById("asn") is just grabbing the same textbox every time, since it's the first element with an ID of "asn" on the page.

Comment: if i write <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "Page on W3"> in this code ,it will not work in eclipse also....why?

Comment: pleas goto this link...i pasted the images over here. and please guide me.     http://www.quora.com/JavaScript/What-is-the-solution-to-get-the-values-of-text-boxes-in-the-cloned-rows-having-same-name-and-insert-into-the-database-using-jsp-and-servlet